# The difference between put and flash Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

What is the difference between put and flash.

```
\Session::flash('flash_message', ' Your article has been created! ');





\Session::put('flash_message', ' Your article has been created! ');
```

When should i use put and when I can use flash ?!

Comment: C'mon. https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+session+flash

Answer (score 3):

> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the `flash` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

> To store data in the session, you will typically use the `put` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#storing-data

Answer (score 0):

The different is:

With `put`, you are basically storing the string `"Your article has been created!"` in the session and it will not be deleted any soon.

With `flash`, you are storing the value in the session and right after another request comes in (e.g: a page refresh) the session would be immediately gone and in that case, the same will also happen to the message (assuming you check before if `Session::has`).

So to answer your question, `Session::put` should be used if you want to store the message for a longer time (e.g: Webshop-Carts). In your case it seems like you just want to give a feedback to the user, so you should use `\Session::flash('flash_message', ' Your article has been created! ');`

Hope that give you a better understanding.